# How replicate data(all dml statement) from one table to another table in different schema oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-insert

I want to replicate table A data to B as we have some different columns in table B. So It is possible to replicate data.

Schema names are different also

example:

**table A**

```
(custome_name, customer_desc,create_date,create_user,update_date,update_user)
```

**table B**

```
(customer_id,custome_name, customer_desc,create_date,create_user,update_date,update_user)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

User `B` has to grant privileges to user `A` so that `A` could insert data into their table:

```
grant insert on table_b to a;
```

Then, user `A` would write an `INSERT` statement, specifying which columns in user `B`'s `table_b` will be populated with which column values from `table_a`

```
INSERT INTO b.table_b (custome_name,
                       customer_desc,
                       create_date,
                       create_user,
                       update_date,
                       update_user)
   SELECT custome_name,
          customer_desc,
          create_date,
          create_user,
          update_date,
          update_user
     FROM table_a;
```

That's it.

---

If users reside in different databases, you'd use a **database link**.